# How to unit test a method of react component?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, chai, enzyme

I am trying to unit test my reactjs component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import store from '../../../store'
import lodash from 'lodash'

export class AddToOrder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {checked: false}
    //debugger
  }
  checkBoxChecked() {
    return true
  }
  render() {
    console.log('testing=this.props.id',this.props.id )
    return (
      <div className="order">
        <label>
          <input
            id={this.props.parent}
            checked={this.checkBoxChecked()}
            onChange={this.addToOrder.bind(this, this.props)}
            type="checkbox"/>
          Add to order
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AddToOrder;
```

Just to get started I am already struggling to assert the checkBoxChecked method:

```js
import React from 'react-native';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {AddToOrder} from '../app/components/buttons/addtoorder/addtoorder';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')
global.document = doc
global.window = doc.defaultView

let props;
beforeEach(() => {
  props = {
    cart: {
      items: [{
        id: 100,
        price: 2000,
        name:'Docs'
      }]
    }
  };
});

describe('AddToOrder component', () => {
  it('should be handling checkboxChecked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AddToOrder {...props.cart} />);
    expect(wrapper.checkBoxChecked()).equals(true); //error appears here
  });
});
```

```

How can I unit test a method on the component? This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
```

Comment: Why are you exporting your component twice?

Comment: to avoid errors

Comment: You can import once by import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme'; Instead of two imports one for mount and one for shallow

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You are almost there. Just change your expect to this:

```
expect(wrapper.instance().checkBoxChecked()).equals(true);
```

You can go through [this link](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208) to know more about testing component methods using enzyme

Comment: Hello, really appreciate your solution, it helped me a lot too.
Do you know if there's a way to test component functions with pure jest without enzyme?

Comment: hey @AttilaMolnár pretty late on the reply, but you should be able to do `MyComponent.prototype.method()`. React just attaches the methods to the `prototype`.

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Thanks to answers like this, I'm being able to learn about testing more than ever :) thanks!

Comment: @xenetics that actually doesn't work, because of closure

Answer (score 12):

For those who find the accepted answer as not working, try using `.dive()` on your shallow wrapper before using `.instance()`:

```
expect(wrapper.dive().instance().somePrivateMethod()).toEqual(true);
```

Reference: [Testing component methods with enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208#issuecomment-330299875)

Comment: This is only needed if you have wrapped your component in something, for example Redux connect method.

Answer (score 1):

Extend of previous answer.
If you have connected component (Redux) , try next code :

```
 const store=configureStore();
  const context = { store };
   const wrapper = shallow(
      <MyComponent,
      { context },
    );
   const inst = wrapper.dive().instance();
   inst.myCustomMethod('hello');
```