# Jest : Test method in reactjs component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jestjs

I have functional component FilterBar -

```
const FilterBar=()=>{

....
....
useEffects..
states...

function apiCallToFilters()
{
  ...
  ...
}

...
..

}
```

Since entire code cannot be shared , I have shared a structure and a method which I want to test from jest.

I have written FilterBar.test.tsx -

```
describe('Filter Bar', () => {
  it('All Api Calls', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FilterBar />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().apiCallToFilters //not able to find apiCallToFilters method here
  });
});
```

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196561/how-to-unit-test-a-method-of-react-component?msclkid=6275f863d11511ecbe8e18b0c96194b0) question from SO.

After having wrapper.instance().  I am getting below properties and methods -

```
context
forceUpdate
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate
props
render
setState
shouldComponentUpdate
state
```

How can I test apiCallToFilters method in FilterBar from jest?

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped resolve your question, would you mind accepting it? Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enzyme` - the library that gives programmatic access to a component instance's properties can only give access to properties that are accessible from outside as it cannot violate JavaScript's encapsulation principles.

I cannot see what kind of a component you are using from in your example code, but I would strongly advise you to convert it to a class component and change the `apiCallToFilters` function into a method (by removing the `function` keyword).

Link to a thread where this is called out can be found [here](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/208#issuecomment-947797955).